# Angular: Show Reactive Form Validation Message with 'form.errors' or '!form.valid'

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have been using reactive form in my Angular project in many places and last week we decided to optimize our code a bit. During code review I have found an issue regarding showing form validation messages in HTML.

So I have used below code to show validation error messages:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
    <input formControlName="firstName">
    <div *ngIf="form.controls.firstName.errors && (form.controls.firstName.touched || form.controls.firstName.dirty)">
        This field is required
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

It seems fine, but what if I replace `form.controls.firstName.errors` with `!form.controls.firstName.valid` See below:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
    <input formControlName="firstName">
    <div *ngIf="!form.controls.firstName.valid && (form.controls.firstName.touched || form.controls.firstName.dirty)">
        This field is required
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I couldn't see any difference at all but in my team some of team mates has opinion that we should use `!form.controls.firstName.valid` and we had long discussion on this small issue. I still didn't convince with my team mates. For me if `form` has an `error` then it's status will be `invalid` or `form` is `invalid` because it has an `error`.

Could anyone suggest me which option we should follow and is correct fundamentally.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A validator function is going to return an object literal of errors if there is an error or null otherwise.  The falsiness of the result is how angular know determines if a control is valid.  So you can presume that the result will be functionally equivalent if you use `.error` or `!...valid`.

The being said using `!...valid` (or more appropriately `.invalid`) is the more definitive approach and if you look at [Angular's examples](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) that is how they do it.

I look at this way:  Who knows in the future of if the behavior you're depending on is always going to be the same?  There might be a legitimate case in the future where errors is null but the control is still invalid.  Best to take the most explicit approach when there is no additional cost in doing so.

*EDIT*

Actually look at the source for `AbstractControl` potentially errors can be empty but the control can still be invalid depending on the implementation of the `_anyControls()` function:

```
get invalid(): boolean { return this.status === INVALID; }

/*...*/

private _calculateStatus(): string {
  if (this._allControlsDisabled()) return DISABLED;
  if (this.errors) return INVALID;
  if (this._anyControlsHaveStatus(PENDING)) return PENDING;
  /* if the condition below is true that means the control will be invalid
   * but errors will be null. */
  if (this._anyControlsHaveStatus(INVALID)) return INVALID;
  return VALID;
}
```

Given that conditions are possible that `errors` can be null but the control status still be `invalid`, then you should definitely be checking `invalid` and not `errors`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Daniel. I am convinced with last part of your reply: ‘Best to take the most explicit approach when there is no additional cost doing so.’ Since our project is large so I was bit confused.

Comment: You might want to see my updated answer.  You should definitely use invalid.

Comment: Wow that’s great. Really an eye opener. I didn’t pay much in-depth attention. Appreciate for your efforts. Thanks!